# Using lambda to define a function based on another: How do I keep my code generic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have some python code that defines a new function based on an old one. It looks like this

```
def myFunction(a: int, b: int, c: int):
    # Do stuff

myNewFunction = lambda a, b: myFunction(a, b, 0)
```

My new function is the same as the old function, but sets the last argument to 0.

My question: Say I did not know the function took three arguments. Can I make the above solution more generic? An invalid solution with the right intention might be something like:

```
def myFunction(a: int, b: int, c: int):
    # Do stuff

func_args = myFunction.__code__.co_varnames
func_args = func_args[:-1]

myNewFunction = lambda *func_args : myFunction(*func_args, 0)
```

Comment: I don't have **co_argvars** `'co_argvars' in dir(myFunction.__code__)` results to *False*.

Comment: Yes, it unfortunately doesn't exist. But I can see how it makes the question confusing. I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct, you can use `functools.partial` this way(instead of lambda):

```py
from functools import partial

def myFunction(a: int, b: int, c: int):
    print(a, b, c)

last_param_name = myFunction.__code__.co_varnames[-1]
new_func = partial(myFunction, **{last_param_name: 0})

new_func(10, 20)
```

Technically `partial` is not a function it's a class but I don't think this is what you concern about.

A pure Python (roughly)equivalent of the original `partial` exists in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) if you want it to be a function type:

```py
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```